# Send data from an android app to a Serial COM Port via Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, port

I would like to send and receive data from my phone to an application on my computer that just connect to a PORT COM and can also send and receive data (like an UART). An exemple of such software (on the computer) is Termite.

For the Android app, I tried with the Bluetoothchat that Android support provides but when I try to connect to my computer, it says it is unable to connect.

I don't know if I am doing it correctly because on the computer software, you have to choose the Baud rate for the UART communication but BT has no baudrate.

Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had actually 2 problems going on :

- I had to go in the settings of my Bluetooth dongle and create a Bluetooth COM Port associated with it
- I had to change in the code the UUID (Universally Unique Identifier): the UUID for the SPP (Serial Port Service) is defined by the Bluetooth SIG to be 0x1101. If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board, then try using the "well-known" SPP UUID : 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB with this code line:

`private static final UUID MY_UUID_SECURE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`

(I put the same for both MY_UUID_SECURE and MY_UUID_INSECURE just to check if it was working)

And then this solved my problem. Hope it can help some people who have the same problems.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to do pairing step between your phone and your computer in order to establish a channel (an RfComm channel) to exchange data.

I suggest you to download a bluetooth terminal like this one from the store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm&hl=en

Comment: I just did and when I try to connect with my computer the application says "unable to connect the device". But I already manage to pair it before and to send pictures from the computer that's why I don't understand